# What exactly did Jar Jar do to get banished?

Tags: star-wars, the-phantom-menace, jar-jar-binks

In *The Phantom Menace*, we learn that Jar Jar was banished from Otoh Gunga for his 'clumsiness'. His explanation is unintelligible nonsense.

> **JAR JAR:** *Tis a long tale, buta small part wawdabe mesa...ooooh...aaaa.....clumsy.*
>
> **OBI-WAN:** *They banished you because you're clumsy?*
>
> **JAR JAR:** *Mesa cause-ed mabee one or duey lettal bitty axadentes...yud-say **boom da gasser, un crash Der Bosses heyblibber...den banished.***
>
> <sub><sup>[The Phantom Menace: Original Screenplay](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Phantom-Menace.html)</sup></sub>

---

**What *precisely* did he do that merited banishment? What laws did he break and what punishment does he face if he returns from exile?**

Comment: ummm., *exist*?

Comment: @Shreedhar - They seem willing to tolerate his existence.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Jar Jar's *'lettal bitty axadantes'* (little bitty accidents).

The story of Jar Jar's exile was addressed in the *[Episode 1 Adventures](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Episode_I_Adventures_(Scholastic))* gamebooks. Jar Jar was working in the kitchens at Boss Nass' mansion. Binks was assigned the job of preparing party food in a "[gasser](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Gasser)" (essentially a large plasma-fired grill with a circular door) in preparation for a party held by Boss Nass for the great and good of Otoh Gunga. In a fit of pique at being accused of clumsiness, Jar Jar kicked the door of the gasser and it got stuck.

> Fassa turned with a sigh and left the kitchen. After she was gone, Jar Jar looked down at the gasser and gave the circular door a swift kick. If only my no on probation, he thought to himself. Den mabee Fassa liken my.
>
> <sub><sup>[Episode 1 Adventures #12: The Bongo Rally](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Episode_I_Adventures_12:_The_Bongo_Rally)</sup></sub>

To make matters worse, he then used a metal spatula to try to wedge the door open and dropped it into the gasser's mechanism.

> Jar Jar rummaged through a kitchen drawer and found a long metal
> spatula. He inserted the spatula between the gasser's door and the
> door's frame, but when he pushed down on the spatula to pry the door
> open, it broke off inside the gasser.
>
> <sub><sup>[Episode 1 Adventures #12: The Bongo Rally](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Episode_I_Adventures_12:_The_Bongo_Rally)</sup></sub>

A few minutes later a build-up of plasma caused the gasser to explode ('*boomed*'), damaging the electrostatic bubble around the mansion and causing it to flood.

> Jar Jar's words were cut off by a massive explosion in the kitchen area. The explosion was immediately followed by a blast of water that geysered from the kitchen door and into the banquet room.
>
> "Da bubble field musta blown!" somebody shouted as water quickly flooded the banquet room,
>
> <sub><sup>[Episode 1 Adventures #12: The Bongo Rally](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Episode_I_Adventures_12:_The_Bongo_Rally)</sup></sub>

Recognising that the flooding would cause the upper floor of the mansion to collapse on Boss Nass' [heyblibber](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Heyblibber/Legends) ("*a luxury submarine*" capable of seating 24), Jar Jar took it upon himself to try to move it. In his panic he crashed it, then abandoned it to its fate.

> From his position, Jar Jar could clearly see that if the upper habitat bubble rolled far enough, it would smash down and crush the sub pen bubble.
>
> ...
>
> Thinking only of saving the heyblibber. Jar Jar sprang for the luxury sub and scrambled into the cockpit.
>
> ...
>
> The heyblibber shot forward so fast that Jar Jar fell over, and the sub smashed into the stairway that led up to the mansion. Jar Jar looked out of the heyblibber's viewport and saw the sub pen's utanode braces buckling under the pressure from the mansion bubble.  At that moment, Jar Jar knew there was only one thing left to do. He jumped out of the heyblibber and swam for his life.
>
> <sub><sup>[Episode 1 Adventures #12: The Bongo Rally](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Episode_I_Adventures_12:_The_Bongo_Rally)</sup></sub>

### Jar Jar's '*pune-ishment*'

Due to the embarrassment caused to Boss Nass and the damage caused to the city, he was convicted under the ['*Nocombackie Law*'](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Nocombackie_Law) (exile) and sent to the surface. The punishment for breaking this law was, we learn, ***being pounded to death***, although it's not immediately apparent whether this would actually happen to him or was merely a symbolic punishment.

> "Binkss brokeen da nocombackie law," the Boss answered. "Hisen to be pune-ished."
> "He has been a great help to us," Qui-Gon said. "I hope the punishment will not be too severe."
> Boss Nass's face hardened. "Pounded unto death!"
>
> <sub><sup>[Episode 1 Adventures #13: Danger on Naboo](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Episode_I_Adventures_13:_Danger_on_Naboo)</sup></sub>

Comment: Honestly, I wonder what happened to the people who built such a shoddy oven!

Comment: @nick012000 Now don't be harsh. One can make a gadget fool-proof. You can even make it idiot-proof. With extreme effort you can even make it child-proof. But no force in this universe can make anything JarJar-proof. That would be stopping an Unstoppable Force. The repercussions of doing so may paradox the universe into oblivion. It's close enough to de-materializing from embarrassment just from having to contain the Binks.